# get data from two separate models and displaying them on my page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

---

im creating a search engine that can display data gotten from two different models. (the first model):

```
var HealthInstitution = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: String,
    phonenumber: String,
    institution_type: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Institution' }, 
    search_keyword: [String],
    website: String,
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
HealthInstitution.index({'$**': 'text'});
```

**and the second** :

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: String,
    middle_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email: String,
    phone_number: String,
    specialty: String,
    search_keyword: [String],
    name_of_institution: String,
    type_of_institution: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Institution' },
    type_of_profession: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Profession' },
    password: String,
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    update_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
User.index({'$**': 'text'});
```

hence ive created the index part of this, but right now i'm having issues write a code in the controller.js that would enable the search engine to pick information from both models. thank you.

Comment: between what the search engine is getting its info from is the variable "search_keyword"

Comment: There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55021961/edit) link on your question. Please use that to add new information instead of adding comments.